# EventHandler when item is added to StackPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there any way I can fire an EventHandler when an object is added to a StackPanel?

My objective is to add a mousedown event to the StackPanel objects.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Please add some details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies, I have added my reasoning as above. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StackPanel` has no events specifically related to adding/removing items from it's collection.

You can however, use the `LayoutUpdated` event. The only issue here is that you will not know *what* item has been added, only that something has been changed.

That being said, the only way (that I am aware) of to add/remove items from a StackPanel is through C#, be it from an `ObservableCollection` binding, or manually modifiying the collection. So in theory, you should **already know** when an item is added/removed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I actually should be using the ObservableCollection method (currently not) so you are correct that I will know when the collection changes. I was hoping for a += new EventHandler to save me some trouble however.

Comment: I have used the layoutupdated event to add an event to the individual objects of the StackPanel. Thanks again, this should solve my problem.